# Finding rows in a table with a foreign key pointing back at itself where the referenced row differs in a certain column

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I can't formulate my question, so I will try to explain here and hopefully change the title later on.

I have a table

```
Organisations (
   id,
   platform_id,
   parent_id
)
```

Here is the tricky part: `organisation.id` represents a number for said organisation, but the same goes for the `parent_id`, it is basically another organisation. `platform_id` is either 1 or 2.

Now what I'm trying to do is to select all organisations where the `parent_id is not null`, but also where `platform_id` of the two organizations represented by `organisation.id` and `organisation.parent_id` is different.

How can I structure it, so that I can use the `parent_id` to search it as normal `id`, so that I can get its `platform_id` as well?

I will try to explain better and shorter perhaps:

I want to be able to filter those organisations, whose `parent_id` have different `platform_id`s, for that I would need to perhaps do a second select somehow...

sorry it got even more confusing.

This is the same table, `parent_id` is just another `id` that is linked to it, so that means that I can somehow access `parent.id` as normal `id` and get its `platform_id`...

In short, I want to list all IDs, that have `parent_id`s where the `platform_id` is different than the `parents_id`'s `platform_id`, however I don't know how to get the 'parents_id`'s`platform_id`.

Comment: So I have
    `select o.id, o.name, o.parent_id, o.platform_id from organization o
    where o.parent_id is not null `

and I also want, to somehow get the parent_id and search it a second time as if it is the o.id , so that I can also get its parent_id.

Comment: the word you're looking for is "self-join"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Organisation t1
JOIN Organisation t2 ON t1.id = t2.parent_id
                    AND t1.platform_id != t2.platform_id;
```

Comment: Thank you! can you also guide me to where I can clarify a `where t1.parent_id is not null`

Comment: @Ruthock Inner join with `t1.id = t2.parent_id` do not allow NULLs.

Comment: This indeed selects the parent, can I somehow include in the select the ID of the child organisation?

Comment: t2.id listed the desired child organisation!
Many thanks guys, solved!

Answer (score 1):

As you have made abundantly and redundantly clear, you want to find all organizations where the organization referenced by `parent_id` has a different `platform_id`.

Translating that into SQL, you get a `EXISTS` condition:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM organisations o
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM organisations op
              WHERE o.parent_id = op.id
                AND o.platform_id <> op.platform_id);
```

You could also write it as a self join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.*
FROM organisations o
   JOIN organisations op
      ON o.parent_id = op.id
WHERE o.platform_id <> op.platform_id;
```

See what performs best.

Comment: Thank you, both work while the second version allows me to select information for the parents.